# Redis on Ubuntu docker: sysctl: setting key "vm.overcommit_memory": Read-only file system

Tags: docker, redis

Using a container docker based on Ubuntu 14.04 image.

Downloaded Redis from official repository

```
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
```

and installed.

Trying to set

```
sudo sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1
```

return

```
sysctl: setting key "vm.overcommit_memory": Read-only file system
```

How to solve?

Thank you

Comment: what is your base image ?

Comment: so you need to set the command on your host first so docker can see it , see this https://github.com/openfirmware/docker-redis/issues/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only a limited number of `sysctl` values [support namespacing](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#sysctl) -- that is, can be set in a container without also modifying the host.

All other values will be read-only inside your containers in order to prevent containers from modifying the host configuration. You'll need to set them on the host -- where they will affect the host and all containers.